# Check to see if there are uncommited changes in any branch of git repo

Tags: bash, git, github, bitbucket

As I am in the process of moving from Bitbucket to Github, I am going through a long list of repositories on my computer that I *should have* been better about maintaining, but haven't been looked at or thought of in awhile. I'm manually going from repo to repo checking to see if there are any uncommitted changes on any existing branch.

I'd like to do this with one command, rather than doing 'git status' on each branch, but I'm unsure of how exactly to do this as I'm not very proficient writing bash scripts.

I am currently running Linux.

Comment: The question as asked doesn't quite make sense. A repository comes with a work-tree. In Git since 2.5 you can add extra work-trees as well, using `git worktree add`. If you haven't done that you have at most the one work-tree. Each work-tree has an index, and the index-and-work-tree combination can match the branch tip (no changes to worry about) or not-match (there may be uncommitted changes). So given one repository with no extra `git worktree add`ed work-trees, there can only be the one branch, and `git status` will tell you about the (single) branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command may help

```
git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline
```

Any lines which don't flow back in to the main branch indicate branches with un-merged changes.